# How to customize the move-to popup in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a requirement where I need to customize the move to popup in Alfresco share such that in the destination section I only need to show Repository and My User Home and not  sites . Can anyone provide a solution on how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently to hide the repository. Override the classpath (**site-webscripts/org/alfresco/**) **modules/documentlibrary/global-folder.get.html** display template for the popup dialog.
Of course to find out such things in the future, it's best to enable surfbug or watch for the ajax call(s) made in your browser dev console (e.g. firebug, dragonfly) before the dialog pops up. Either or a combination of both will help you find what you're looking for.